# How do I save bookmarks to the Bookmarks Bar by default?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Whenever I go to bookmark a page a folder called *References* is always the default option. I save a majority of my bookmarks to the Bookmarks Bar though. How  can I change it so that bookmarks are saved to the Bookmarks Bar by default?

Comment: Google Chrome should set the default bookmarks save location to the last one used. Is the folder `References` still the default folder after you've saved to the Bookmarks Bar?

Comment: Looks like it's a common issue - [link 1](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84880), [link 2](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98986).

Comment: @amiregelz Yep, that's the problem. I've starred the issue so I'll get an email when it's solved.